# Sendfile bug with Virtualbox, Vagrant and Cowboy

Tags: vagrant, elixir, virtualbox, phoenix-framework

I'm using Vagrant with a Virtualbox provider to run a Elixir/Phoenix project but I'm running into this issue (https://www.getconvey.com/devblog/virtualbox-still-hates-sendfile/), is there a way to disable sendfile in the Cowboy web server?

Comment: Are you using cowboy directly or phoenix or plug static? Most of them have a way to disable sendfile, but you need to be more specific where you use it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new with phoenix I'm just using `mix phoenix.server` right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy to report that I've solved this issue in my own installation, details below:

Another option for working around the sendfile issue is to use NFS for shared directories. This is the Vagrant config I've used that's working well:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/host/path/", "/guest/path/", type: "nfs", :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1']
```

Great! One problem solved, however, the inotify functionality that Phoenix uses for live reload detection doesn't work with NFS...

To resolve that issue, install this vagrant plugin: https://github.com/mhallin/vagrant-notify-forwarder

After those two and a reload of the guest machine, live reload works perfectly

Also note that if Cowboy ever gets the ability to disable sendfile, this workaround would not be necessary I'm guessing. The relevant issue for that fix is: https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/issues/812